# ways of importing paramiko library

Tags: python, paramiko

I would like to know if there is any `paramiko` library that you can put in the same folder as the python program that uses `paramiko` for importing it this way or on the other hand the only way to use paramiko is installing it before.

With pexpect you can put a `pexpect.py` in the same folder and it is working that way, without installing it.

Thanks and BR/

Answer (score 0):

You have to download source code for `paramiko` from [github](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/master/paramiko) and place that in your folder from where you have to import.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I have done it, I was missing pycrypto package. I have downloaded pycrypto and it is a c package so I think I have to install it in the machine, i can not import it without installing it. Is this correct?. Thanks

Comment: yes you have to install `pycrypto` then you can use it in `paramiko`